# trying to import XML file to a Master/Detail sql table

Tags: sql, xml

trying to use SQL stored Proc. to import XML to tables. I would like the MemberInformation section email_address,first_name,last_name inserted into master.  then Instances inserted into "Instances" table with Master Key. then Transactions inserted into "Transactions" table with master key.  attached is the example XML.

```
    <ArrayOfMemberInformation>
  <MemberInformation Member_Id="111111" Constituent_Id="" Last_Updated="2012-02-01T14:10:57" Last_Updated_By_Constituent_Id="" Last_Updated_By_Name="Jon doe">
    <Column Name="email_address" Value="jdoe@sample.net" />
    <Column Name="first_name" Value="Jon " />
    <Column Name="last_name" Value="Doe" />
    <Column Name="email_address" Value="jdoe@sample.net" />
    <Column Name="first_name" Value="Jon " />
    <Column Name="last_name" Value="Doe" />
    <Instances>
      <Instance Instance_Id="333333-4545-8C4543-6676756">
        <Column Name="ac member" Value="Y" />
         <Column Name="ac gradyear" Value="1833" />
        <Column Name="ac line1" Value="Doe  FAMILY" />
        <Column Name="ac line2" Value="'69  '92    " />
        <Column Name="ac line3" Value="'95  '99" />
        <Column Name="ac line4" Value="" />
        <Column Name="ac line5" Value="" />
         <Column Name="receiptpreference" Value="" />
        <Transactions>
          <Transaction Transaction_Id="11111" IsSuccess="true" IsReviewed="true">
            <Column Name="amount" Value="5.0000" />
             <Column Name="billingname" Value="Jon doe" />
             <Column Name="achchecknum" Value="" />
             <Column Name="billingemail" Value="adDoe7@comcast.net" />
            <Column Name="billingphone" Value="111-222-22222" />
            <Column Name="billingstreet1" Value="44 kel Ct" />
            <Column Name="billingstreet2" Value="" />
            <Column Name="billingcity" Value="city" />
            <Column Name="billingstate" Value="OH" />
            <Column Name="billingzip" Value="55555" />
            <Column Name="billingcountry" Value="US" />

            <TransactionItems>
              <TransactionItem I_Member_Id="222222" Type="Amt" Transaction_Item_Id="Amount-1111">
                <Column Name="total" Value="5.0000" />
              </TransactionItem>
            </TransactionItems>
            <LinkedTransaction>
              <TransactionId>0</TransactionId>
              <Amount>0</Amount>
              <ControlId>0</ControlId>
              <ControlType />
              <ControlName />
              <PaymentType />
              <TotalScheduledAmount>0</TotalScheduledAmount>
            </LinkedTransaction>
            <LedgerValues>
              <LedgerValue Name="ALLCOE " Value="PREP" />
            </LedgerValues>
          </Transaction>
        </Transactions>
      </Instance>
    </Instances>
  </MemberInformation>
</ArrayOfMemberInformation>
```

Comment: Sounds good. Do you have a question?

Comment: sorry, yes i can get the main MemberInfo. using a cursor but it reads all the members and skips the details. DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
with cteCastToXML as (
    select CAST( yourXML as xml) as x
        from  #xml
)
select h.ep.value('@Name','varchar(100)') as [Type],
       h.ep.value('@Value', 'varchar(100)') as [Key]
    from cteCastToXML
        cross apply x.nodes('/ArrayOfMemberInformation/MemberInformation/Column') as h(ep)

 
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Name,@value

Comment: @Doug please edit your question adding this code. It shouldn't be in the comments.

Comment: Also what database system are you using?

Comment: It is probably easier to read xml in an external programming language and then insert to database.  I've done it before using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is far away from *clear*...

What I can guess, is that you want to read from this XML. I'd suggest to read into a staging table. Then you can proceed with tabular data. You might add columns for the ref-Ids, get all this settled in the staging table and the shift your data to the target tables.

I did not want to do all the work for you, but the following will read at least one value from any location in your XML. This will give you enough to find all the other values yourself. Try it out and come back with a more specific (new) question.

```
    DECLARE @xml XML=
    N'<ArrayOfMemberInformation>
      <MemberInformation Member_Id="111111" Constituent_Id="" Last_Updated="2012-02-01T14:10:57" Last_Updated_By_Constituent_Id="" Last_Updated_By_Name="Jon doe">
        <Column Name="email_address" Value="jdoe@sample.net" />
        <Column Name="first_name" Value="Jon " />
        <Column Name="last_name" Value="Doe" />
        <Column Name="email_address" Value="jdoe@sample.net" />
        <Column Name="first_name" Value="Jon " />
        <Column Name="last_name" Value="Doe" />
        <Instances>
          <Instance Instance_Id="333333-4545-8C4543-6676756">
            <Column Name="ac member" Value="Y" />
            <Column Name="ac gradyear" Value="1833" />
            <Column Name="ac line1" Value="Doe  FAMILY" />
            <Column Name="ac line2" Value="''69  ''92    " />
            <Column Name="ac line3" Value="''95  ''99" />
            <Column Name="ac line4" Value="" />
            <Column Name="ac line5" Value="" />
            <Column Name="receiptpreference" Value="" />
            <Transactions>
              <Transaction Transaction_Id="11111" IsSuccess="true" IsReviewed="true">
                <Column Name="amount" Value="5.0000" />
                <Column Name="billingname" Value="Jon doe" />
                <Column Name="achchecknum" Value="" />
                <Column Name="billingemail" Value="adDoe7@comcast.net" />
                <Column Name="billingphone" Value="111-222-22222" />
                <Column Name="billingstreet1" Value="44 kel Ct" />
                <Column Name="billingstreet2" Value="" />
                <Column Name="billingcity" Value="city" />
                <Column Name="billingstate" Value="OH" />
                <Column Name="billingzip" Value="55555" />
                <Column Name="billingcountry" Value="US" />
                <TransactionItems>
                  <TransactionItem I_Member_Id="222222" Type="Amt" Transaction_Item_Id="Amount-1111">
                    <Column Name="total" Value="5.0000" />
                  </TransactionItem>
                </TransactionItems>
                <LinkedTransaction>
                  <TransactionId>0</TransactionId>
                  <Amount>0</Amount>
                  <ControlId>0</ControlId>
                  <ControlType />
                  <ControlName />
                  <PaymentType />
                  <TotalScheduledAmount>0</TotalScheduledAmount>
                </LinkedTransaction>
                <LedgerValues>
                  <LedgerValue Name="ALLCOE " Value="PREP" />
                </LedgerValues>
              </Transaction>
            </Transactions>
          </Instance>
        </Instances>
      </MemberInformation>
    </ArrayOfMemberInformation>';
```

--The query will shred some of the values into a staging table:

```
SELECT mi.value('@Member_Id','int') Attribute_MemberId --attribute of MemberInformation
      ,mi.value('(Column[@Name="email_address"]/@Value)[1]','nvarchar(max)') PickThecolumnByName_eMail
      ,mi.value('(Column[@Name="first_name"]/@Value)[1]','nvarchar(max)') PickThecolumnByName_FirstName
      ,inst.value('@Instance_Id','nvarchar(max)') Instance_Id
      ,inst.value('(Column[@Name="ac member"]/@Value)[1]','nvarchar(max)') Instance_AcMember
      ,trns.value('@Transaction_Id','nvarchar(max)') Transaction_Id
      ,trns.value('(Column[@Name="amount"]/@Value)[1]','decimal(12,4)') Transaction_Amount
      ,trns.value('(LinkedTransaction/TransactionId)[1]','int') LikedTransactionId
INTO #stagingTable
FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfMemberInformation/MemberInformation') A(mi)
OUTER APPLY A.mi.nodes('Instances/Instance') B(inst)
OUTER APPLY B.inst.nodes('Transactions/Transaction') C(trns);
```

--Check the result;

```
SELECT * FROM #stagingTable
```